# When do moves end?

Tags: actions, pokemon-tabletop-united

There are a lot of moves that have lingering effects. For the purpose of this question, let's take "ingrain" as an example. Ingrain states:

> Ingrain applies a Coat to the user, which has the
> following effect; the user cannot be pushed or pulled,
> and cannot be switched out. At the beginning of each of
> the user’s turn, the user gains a Tick of Hit Points.

Does this last until the end of the scene? Or can the user end this effect at their own volition? If the latter, what kind of action does it take to end this effect?

Comment: @Medix2 Powder is another example of a coat with some negative effects-- in that case the effects are pretty much *all* negative, though: it's an offensive move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Non-permanent effects end when the Scene/Encounter ends

Coats (and nearly every effect or Move that is not explicitly permanent) are intended to end when Encounters/Scenes end. I asked the Developers in the PTU Discord about this and was told:

> Like all Coats (and most effects besides permanent ones), it ends at the end of Scene [...]

> [...] Coats (and Blessings, and all other temporary Conditions) expire at the end of combat, as if they were Combat Stages or Volatile Conditions. That is how they are intended to work.

I could not find anything explicitly stating that this happens but it is what's intended and has consistently been a rule at every table I've been a part of.

---

#### Coats can *also* end when something specificlaly ends them

Ingrain is a Coat and page 339 under Move Keywords states:

> [...] Moves with the Coat keyword give the targets a certain effect while the Coat persists. Coats may be passed on by Baton Pass. [...]

Notably, nothing states that switching out ends Coats, and nothing details a general way to willing end them. Thus, Coats persists until an effect specifically ends them (such as the Wash Away Ability and Clear Smog Move).

An example of a Coat with an alternative method of ending it early is Water Sport (page 435):

> [...] After a target has been hit by a damaging Fire Type Move, the coat is removed. [...]

---

#### Use Ingrain when you are prepared to stay in the battle

It happens that almost every Coat is entirely beneficial and there would be no reason to remove it early; Ingrain, as you've pointed out, is an exception to this:

> [...] The user cannot be pushed or pulled, and cannot be switched out. At the beginning of each of the user’s turn, the user gains a Tick of Hit Points. [...]

After you use Ingrain you've decided you are staying in the battle and are not going to get recalled or switched out. I found no way of ending Ingrain outside of using a move such as Clear Smog or an Ability such as Wash Away.

---

A possible tiny exception to what I just stated is Smeargle, who could learn both Ingrain and Baton Pass which states (page 391):

> The user is replaced with another Pokémon from their trainer’s roster. All Combat Stage, Coats, and [Stratagems] on Baton Pass’ user are transferred to the replacement. Baton Pass may be used to switch even if the user is Trapped.

*Technically* Ingrain does not make a Pokémon Trapped but specifically says it prevents being switched out so whether or not Baton Pass (which ignores being Trapped) works with Ingrain will ultimately be up to the GM and it's also an incredibly unlikely scenario to ever have happen.